# Sampling distribution with large sample size

Tags: random-variables, normal-distribution, sampling

As the sample size $n$ of a sampling distribution of sample means increases, the distribution becomes more normal. But if $n$ were the same size as the (finite) population, the "sampling" distribution would consist of only one possible value, the mean.

So at what point does an increasing $n$ cause a sampling distribution to become less normal?

Comment: You mean "the sampling distribution of the sample mean" I guess. It does not become "less normal", rather, it remains (always approximately) a normal with ever decreasing variance.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Another question: Once n ≥ 30, the distribution is approximately normal, but after 30, does it become even more normal or remain approximately normal?

Comment: Always approximately, for finite $n$. The exact "measure" of "approximate" is not determined.